# invoke-command is unable to locate a file while running on remote computer

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

![Image of Error message][1]

Scripts works fine on local computer. When trying to run on remote computer it was not able to read config.xml file located on script current directory.
 Here is my Code:

```
        function Get-ScriptDirectory 
{ 
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value 
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path 
    #Split-Path -Path $($global:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
    #split-path -parent $psISE.CurrentFile.Fullpath
}

$ScriptRoot = Get-ScriptDirectory

$CurrentPath = $ScriptRoot.ToString()
$Configfile= [xml](get-content "$Currentpath\Config.xml")



# Import variables from XML configuration file
$Configfile= [xml](get-content "$Currentpath\config.xml")


# Get SCCM sourcefile location Options

$Source=$Configfile.config.SCCMClient.SourceDIR
$ExecutableName=$Configfile.config.SCCMClient.FileName
# Get SCCM Options

$configSMSSitecode =$Configfile.config.SCCMConfig.SMSSITECODE
$configManagementPoint = $Configfile.config.SCCMConfig.MP
[int]$configCacheSize = $Configfile.config.SCCMConfig.SCCMCACHE

#=======================================================================================
# SCCM Command line Arguments for Installing SCCM Client

#=======================================================================================

$arguments="/mp:`"$configManagementPoint`" /logon SMSSITECODE=`"$configSMSSitecode`""

function Install-SCCMclient
<# 
.SYNOPSIS
    Function to Install SCCM Client.
.DESCRIPTION
    Function to Install SCCM Client SCCM Client using SWITCHES
.EXAMPLE
    Install-SCCMclient
.PARAMETER Path
    Path of the Source file path 
.PARAMETER ContinueOnError
    Continue if an error is encountered
.NOTES 

#>
{
Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [String] $executablename="ccmsetup.exe",
        [boolean] $ContinueOnError = $true
    )  
    Try{
            $returncode=$null
            if((Test-path $source) -eq $true)
            {

                write-Host "SCCM Source file location path Resolved"
            }
            else{

                write-Host " Unable to resolve SCCM Source file ccmsetup.exe path"
                Exit-script 5020
            }


            #Installs SCCM Client using Switches and captures exits code for Installation
            $process = (Start-Process -WorkingDirectory "$source" -FilePath "$ExecutableName" -ArgumentList "$arguments" -PassThru -Wait)

                #Start-Sleep -s 180
            # Get the exit code for the process

            $returnCode = $process.ExitCode
                if($returncode -eq 0)
                {

                 Write-Host "SCCM Installation Process finished with following exitcode:[$returnCode] " 

                }
                else{
                    Write-Host "SCCM Installation Process Failed with following exitcode:[$returnCode] "
                    }
                    #Write-Host "SCCM Installation Process finished with return code: " $process.Exitcode   
                    #Write-Host "$returnCode"   

        }


Catch [Exception] {
        If ($ContinueOnError -eq $true) {
            Write-Host $("SCCM Client instalaltion completed with the following exit code:" + $_.Exception.Message)
            Continue
        }
        Else {
            Throw $("Could not Install] SCCMClient:" + $_.Exception.Message)
        }
    }
}     
Install-SCCMClient
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shEyg.jpg**strong text**

Comment: please post the code you are working with, along with any errors etc..

Comment: Preferably post the text and not a picture we have to scrap the text from.

Comment: Hi matt, I have updated my code